# Lagrangian multiplier vectorial form

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, numerical-optimization

When i have this problem:

$min f(x)$

$h{_i}(x)=0, i=1,\dots,m$

$g{_j}(x)<=0, j=1,\dots,p$

I can use the Lagrangian multiplier to write function in:

$L(x,\lambda,\mu)=f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^{m} \lambda{_i}h{_i}(x)+\sum_{j=1}^{p} \mu{_j}g{_j}(x)$.

Why can I write this, in this form : $L(x,\lambda,\mu)=f(x)+\lambda^T h(x)+\mu^Tg(x)$ ? I don't understand because i can substituite the sum with $\lambda^T$ and $\mu^T$.

Comment: $h(x)$ is vector, if that helps...

Comment: Ok and in the case of the problem is $min \frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx+c$ with constraint $Ax\leqslant d, Q=Q^T,  A \in \mathbb{R}^{m*n}, b\in \mathbb{R}^n, c \in \mathbb{R}$, i see that in the lagrangian $L(x,\lambda,\mu)=\frac{1}{2}x^TQx-b^Tx+\mu^T(Ax-d)$, the $c$ term is deleted and now $Ax-d$ is not a vector (like $h(x)$ question).